# Using Regex in new MongoDB library for PHP7/HHVM

Tags: php, regex, mongodb

Trying to figure out how to use Regex in new [MongoDB library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php)

I didn't find real world example of usage MongoDB\BSON\Regex so I come up with the code below:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->insert(['word' => ['word' => 'heelo']]);
$bulk->insert(['word' => ['word' => 'hello']]);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.collection', $bulk);

$filter = ['word' => ['word' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("hello","i")]];

$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('db.collection', $query);

foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
```

But it shows nothing. Does anyone know how to use it?

Answer (score 8):

I've found the answer. I should write query like:

```
$filter = ['word.word' => new MongoDB\BSON\Regex("hello","i")];
```

Comment: hi, what does `"i"` stands for ?

Comment: "i" is case-insensitive (or ignore case, but same outcome), in most regex libraries.